# Problem with deserialization after renaming assembly

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, executable, .net-assembly

I have a following problem. In order to change a name of the compiled executable file, I changed the name of the Assembly. But after that I couldn't open an old binary serialized object from the file. I have an SerializationException: "Unable to find assembly "OldAssembly".

I know that it can be solved somehow by creating custom SerializationBinder and overriding BindToType mehod there. But I don't know how to do that.

Any tips or hints are appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just change the name of the assembly back and instead change the name of the executable that gets built?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how changing the name of an assembly will impact the name of an exe file...  Do you mean you changed the name of your Application project?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use [DataContract] or [Serializable] to mark your objects for serialization?

If you use DataContract you can change the xml namespace on your new object so it won't look for the old assembly/type:

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Your.Old.Namespace.ClassName")]

I did this recently when I was moving a serialized type from one assembly to another.

Comment: Thank you for respond, but I am using [Serializable]  attribute.